# Check if a commit occurred on a github page

Tags: java, android, github, git-commit

I'm trying to create a notification in Android.

I want to check if in a github link (for example: https://github.com/Bocci94/csv_corona/blob/master/files.csv) a commit occurred or this csv file has been modified. I need to create a script in Android that somethimes check if there is a modify.

Is this possible?

Thnks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a History button on the page, which displays the history of the file changes.

To access the history in your android app, you can use [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). You can access a file commit history via

http://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=PATH_TO_FILE

For your example, it will be:

http://api.github.com/Bocci94/csv_corona/commits?path=master/files.csv

[image]

Comment: I know, but how can I check if there is new commit with an Android script? There is a library that do it?

Comment: @FrancescoBocci check the updated answer. There will also be another way, where github will push notification to app. Probably one of the starting points will be https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/